# Do dingoes show wolf 'characteristics'?

Tags: evolution, ethology

I've read that Russians have been performing selective breeding on Red Foxes for about fifty years, aiming to make them tame. [The wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Domesticated_Red_Fox) says

> The experiment was initiated by scientists who were interested in the
> topic of domestication and the process by which wolves became tame
> domesticated dogs. They saw some retention of juvenile traits by adult
> dogs, both morphological ones, such as skulls that were unusually
> broad for their length, and behavioral ones, such as whining, barking,
> and submission.

I wonder, since dingoes are completely wild dogs that have only relatively recently split off from domesticated dogs, do they show more 'wolf-like' characteristics? That is, has their life in the wild selected against domestication genes?

Perhaps the best way to phrase the question is ***have dingoes gained more of the genes/traits that silver foxes lost in the Russian domestication experiment?***

Comment: Just to clarify, by "wolf-like characteristic", I suppose you mean "characterstics that are shared with wolves but not with dogs", is that right?

Comment: Well, I suppose "not all dogs", since there may be kinds of dogs that have some of those traits. I guess "non-domesticate traits" might be a better phrase, but the whole subject seems tricky.

Comment: The question is interesting +1. To my knowledge, the level of domestication of Dingo's ancestors is debated. And when having a quick look at the wiki article it seems to be quite a mess indeed. I think one could draw quite a good answer from [wiki>Dingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingo) and its references.